# Azure SignUp policy needs to return to a different application

Tags: azure, security, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, policy

I have an Azure policy which works well for authentication users of different roles. I now need to add a SignUp component to this but there are some requirements that I'm not sure are possible.

1. I need the policy to return back to a different application than what called it. Say App A has the signup link on it's login page which will invoke the
   policy's SignUp userjourney. However, I need it to not return back
   to that same App, instead redirect to App B along with those claims
   it's gathered. Is this even possible?
2. If it were possible (above), how can this be set up under the relyingparty
   section? I would need to keep what is already there for the
   userjourney that authentications users, but now also somehow provide
   what's needed for this SignUp flow.

I am sorry if this is vague. I am just looking to get unstuck. If anyone could provide any sort of nudge in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This idea will not work. This is because, for at least the MSAL authentication library, it will reject a token response if MSAL was not the one who initiated the request. That is built in protection to most libraries, and uses the `state` parameter in the authentication request to apply this protection. Only responses that come back with the same `state` parameter will be accepted by the app.

You need to create a link from App 1 to App 2, and have App 2 initiate the Sign Up B2C policy.

The token response URL is controlled by the `redirect_uri` parameter in the authentication request. Your app will always require this to be configured within it. Both apps should provide a `redirect_uri` to send the token back to the respective App.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests